# How do i return a boolean value from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, tkinter

In the following code im trying to make a login page but i encountered a problem here. the problem is, `print(bool(verfied))` shows a error and says `unresolved reference 'verified'`.I would like the function to return a boolean value after it is called through the button.please help!!

```
def verification():
        verified = False
        if str(username_login.get()) == '1' and str(password_login.get()) == '1':
            verified = True
        elif str(username_login.get()) != '1' and str(password_login.get()) != '1':
            verified = False
        return verified
    login_button = Button(screen, text='Login', command=verification)
    login_button.place(relx=0.5,
                       rely=0.45,
                       anchor='center')
print(bool(verified))
```

Comment: The function seems ok. Maybe you have to call the function 'print(bool(verification())?'

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to fix the code indentation. Also - not the answer to your question, but - your `elif` is unnecessary as `verified` is already set to False at that point.

Comment: I dont see how this is related to `tkinter`

Comment: If your trying to access the variable then I think you need `global` declaration, else you will need to call the function and not the variable name

Comment: Your indentation is a mess. And you are not calling the function.

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, I am not sure if the part after return is part of the function, if so, it will never be executed... your function is too complicated, you might only returt the first if statement instead and I dont see a reason for casting to str and then compare with str instead of int. You should call in the end `print(verification())`

Answer (score 1):

You can also just return a Boolean like this:

```
def verify_login(username_login, password_login):
    if str(username_login.get()) == str(password_login.get()):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```